# localStorage is not working on google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I am using browsers `localStorage` to store a value, but while using google chrome, when we refresh the page using `window.location.reload()`, `localStorage.value` is flushed. e.g

```
localStorage.value1=true
```

after reloading, i am not getting this value1 object in localStorage.

Same code works on mozila firefox, but not in chrome. 
While using firefox, localstorage value is persistent.

Comment: Have you tried to use the [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) and [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) methods of localStorage?

Comment: Just tried this in the console with the latest version of Chrome and it is persistent, that is the purpose of localStorage.

Comment: In addition to `setItem()/getItem()` there's one thing to check: are you using private mode? That may cause problems with localStorage.

Comment: for chrome, it is not working with set and get methods also

Comment: and I am not using private mode also

Answer (score 17, accepted):

LocalStorage supports only string values, not boolean or others.

Method to store and retrieve values:

Put the value into storage

```
localStorage.setItem('value1', 'true');
```

Retrieve the value from storage

```
var val1 = localStorage.getItem('value1');
```

[Read more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)..

Comment: They work if you set them to true (not a string) in Chrome. Is this for Firefox or thing or something? Want to make sure I'm using these correctly for all browsers.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the correct [API for `Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage):

```
window.localStorage.setItem('value1', 'true');
```

What you're doing is setting a property on a variable which won't persist between page loads. Firefox is likely being too smart and recognizing that you want to actually save the value in the browser's local storage store.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
window.localStorage.setItem("value1", true);

var yourvar = window.localStorage.getItem("value1");
```

Answer (score -2):

I just solved my problem with not having local storage read on page reload, I had a option for this written:

```
    if ('darkMode') === 'true') {
  enableDarkMode();
}
```

And it was not working, on reload it was true, but `enableDarkMode()` was not invoking itself. So I looked forward for an answer, and found that changing an statement in *if* option actually solved my problem, so the answer was:
`if (localStorage.getItem('darkMode') === 'true') { enableDarkMode() }`;

Hope that will help some.

Answer (score -3):

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

// Article - Our struct for all articles
type Article struct {
    Id      string    `json:"Id"`
    Title   string `json:"Title"`
    Desc    string `json:"desc"`
    Content string `json:"content"`
}

var Articles []Article

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to the HomePage!")
    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: homePage")
}

func returnAllArticles(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: returnAllArticles")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Articles)
}

func returnSingleArticle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    key := vars["id"]

    for _, article := range Articles {
        if article.Id == key {
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(article)
        }
    }
}


func createNewArticle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // get the body of our POST request
    // unmarshal this into a new Article struct
    // append this to our Articles array.    
    reqBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r)

    var article Article 
    json.Unmarshal(reqBody, &article)
    // update our global Articles array to include
    // our new Article
    Articles = append(Articles, article)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(article)
}

func deleteArticle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    id := vars["id"]

    for index, article := range Articles {
        if article.Id == id {
            Articles = append(Articles[:index], Articles[index+1:]...)
        }
    }

}

func handleRequests() {
    myRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/articles", returnAllArticles)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/article", createNewArticle).Methods("POST")
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/article/{id}", deleteArticle).Methods("DELETE")
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/article/{id}", returnSingleArticle)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":10000", myRouter))
}

func main() {
    Articles = []Article{
        Article{Id: "1", Title: "Hello", Desc: "Article Description", Content: "Article Content"},
        Article{Id: "2", Title: "Hello 2", Desc: "Article Description", Content: "Article Content"},
    }
    handleRequests()
}
```