# How should I persist component state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using redux-persist to persist the store.
But how about "local state"?

For example, user entered some fields and seleceted some options (radio/dropdown).
Since only this component cares about the data, I assume it is bad to put it into store. 
But right now thats what I am doing. When user click submit, I will put `this.state` into store like `{...state, myComponent: {persistStatea: oldState}}`
How should I persist this types of information?

Comment: If the state is not critical enough to move it out to the application store, then it'd make sense to write persistence code within the component which owns the state. You can use `setState` callback parameter to write the state down and `componentDidMount` to rehydrate it. Use whatever storage medium that makes sense.

Comment: There's no harm in putting form state into Redux. There are very popular libraries built around this idea https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/

Answer (score 0):

redux-persist is accessing local storage on web browsers. You can access this directly any time yourself and store whatever you like in there.

```
var { state } = this.state;
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(state))
```

Then to retrieve:

```
var restoredState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'))
```

you need to stringify because https://stackoverflow.com/a/29560595/8896573

Now you just need to find logical points in the life cycle of the component to use these